# States of two particles in 2-level system

Tags: fermions, two-level-system

I have a question regarding the 2 Fermions in Two-level system and the possible states and resulting partition function.
As far as I know, Fermions are forbidden from occupying same quantum states by Pauli exclusion principle. Thus the possible states should look like, 
$$
\underline{\hspace{1cm}} \quad \underline{\uparrow \hspace{0.5cm}} \quad \underline{\downarrow \hspace{0.5cm}}  \quad \underline{\uparrow \hspace{0.5cm}}  \quad \underline{\downarrow \hspace{0.5cm}} \quad \underline{\uparrow\downarrow\hspace{0.6cm}}\\
\underline{\uparrow \downarrow \hspace{0.6cm}} \quad \underline{\downarrow \hspace{0.5cm}} \quad \underline{\downarrow \hspace{0.5cm}}  \quad \underline{\uparrow \hspace{0.5cm}} \quad \underline{\uparrow \hspace{0.5cm}} \quad \underline{\hspace{1cm}}
$$

But from the solutions, I saw it should look like below.
$$
\underline{\hspace{1cm}} \quad \underline{\uparrow \hspace{0.5cm}} \quad \underline{\downarrow \hspace{0.5cm}} \quad \underline{\uparrow\downarrow\hspace{0.6cm}}\\
\underline{\uparrow \downarrow \hspace{0.6cm}} \quad \underline{\downarrow \hspace{0.5cm}} \quad \underline{\uparrow \hspace{0.5cm}} \quad \underline{\hspace{1cm}}
$$

Shouldn't all the spin configuration be possible for the fermions?

Comment: it seems that two additional states can be superposition of your 4 states

Comment: What is the reference?

Comment: All four states below have zero total spin in the $z$ direction. Your reference is probably assuming spin conservation.

Comment: Related : [Total spin of two spin- 1/2  particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342123/total-spin-of-two-spin-1-2-particles/342156#342156).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In general there must be the six states you mentioned. However, one common feature among the 4 states given in the “solution” is that they have total spin of 0. The other two states have a total spin of 1.

In case the system is constrained to have a total spin of 1, then only those 4 states will be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which "solutions" you are talking about, thus I cannot judge why such solutions would only allow 4 states for this system, but in all generality, you are right, and six states are allowed. The spins can be parallel if the fermions are lying on different energy levels.