# Tensor product in matrix form, confusion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, notation

I don't understand the jump from the 3rd to the 4th line of the proof of this statement. Can someone please explain why $|a_m\rangle^{(1)}\langle a_m|^{(1)} \otimes|b_n\rangle^{(2)}\langle b_n|^{(2)}=(|a_m\rangle^{(1)}\otimes |b_n\rangle^{(2)})(\langle a_m|^{(1)}\otimes\langle b_n|^{(2)})  $ ? I know that bras are basically operators and that $\langle a_m|^{(1)}\otimes\langle b_n|^{(2)}$ can therefore be viewed as a tensor product of operators $T\otimes S$ $(T=\langle a_m|^{(1)},S=\langle b_n|^{(2)})$  and that when acting on a tensor product of states $T\otimes S(v\otimes w)=Tv\otimes Sw$. But here the tensor state $(|a_m\rangle^{(1)}\otimes |b_n\rangle^{(2)})$ is left of the tensor operator $(\langle a_m|^{(1)}\otimes\langle b_n|^{(2)})$ ?!? I am so confused with this... 
[image]

The proof is from: http://web.pa.msu.edu/people/mmoore/Lect24_TensorProduct.pdf,  pdf page 8

Comment: The state $\:|c_k\rangle =  |a_m\rangle^{(1)}\otimes |b_n\rangle^{(2)}\:$ is a product state in the product space $\:\mathcal{H}_{12}\:$ and $\: \langle c_k| =  \langle a_m|^{(1)}\otimes\langle b_n|^{(2)} \:$. Then   $\:  |c_k\rangle\langle c_k| =  (|a_m\rangle^{(1)}\otimes |b_n\rangle^{(2)})(\langle a_m|^{(1)}\otimes\langle b_n|^{(2)})\:$ is the known operator - projection of a state in $\:\mathcal{H}_{12}\:$ on the product state $\:|c_k\rangle \:$ for which the symbol $\: |a_m,b_n\rangle^{(12)}\:$ is used later in the proof.

Comment: Yes, but why $|a_m\rangle^{(1)}\langle a_m|^{(1)} \otimes|b_n\rangle^{(2)}\langle b_n|^{(2)}=(|a_m\rangle^{(1)}\otimes |b_n\rangle^{(2)})(\langle a_m|^{(1)}\otimes\langle b_n|^{(2)})  $ ? This is what I don't understand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\:\boldsymbol{\xi}\in \mathcal{H}_{1}\,,\boldsymbol{\eta}\in \mathcal{H}_{2} \:$ and $\:\mathrm{I_{1}}\equiv\text{identity in }\mathcal{H}_{1}\,,\mathrm{I_{2}}\equiv\text{identity in }\mathcal{H}_{2} \:$

\begin{align}
&\left(|a\rangle\langle a|\otimes|b\rangle\langle b|\right)\left(|\boldsymbol{\xi}\rangle\otimes|\boldsymbol{\eta}\rangle\right) =\left(|a\rangle\langle a|\boldsymbol{\xi}\rangle\right)\otimes\left(|b\rangle\langle b|\boldsymbol{\eta}\rangle\right)=
\nonumber\\
& \left(\langle a|\boldsymbol{\xi}\rangle \mathrm{I_{1}}|a\rangle\right)\otimes\left(\langle b|\boldsymbol{\eta}\rangle\mathrm{I_{2}}|b\rangle\right)=
\left[\left(\langle a|\boldsymbol{\xi}\rangle \mathrm{I_{1}}\right)\otimes\left(\langle b|\boldsymbol{\eta}\rangle\mathrm{I_{2}}\right)\right]\left(|a\rangle\otimes|b\rangle\right)=
\tag{01}\\
& \underbrace{\left[\left(\langle a|\mathrm{I_{1}}\right)\otimes\left(\langle b|\mathrm{I_{2}}\right)\right]\left(|\boldsymbol{\xi}\rangle\otimes|\boldsymbol{\eta}\rangle\right)}_{\textrm{scalar quantity}}\left(|a\rangle\otimes|b\rangle\right)=\left(|a\rangle\otimes|b\rangle\right)\underbrace{\left(\langle a|\otimes\langle b|\right)\left(|\boldsymbol{\xi}\rangle\otimes|\boldsymbol{\eta}\rangle\right)}_{\textrm{scalar quantity}}
\nonumber
\end{align}
so
\begin{equation}
\left(|a\rangle\langle a|\otimes|b\rangle\langle b|\right)= \left(|a\rangle\otimes|b\rangle\right)\left(\langle a|\otimes\langle b|\right)
\tag{02}
\end{equation}
Note that a scalar multiple of a vector $\:\mathbf{x}\:$ in a linear space, for example   $\:\mathbf{y}=z\cdot\mathbf{x}\:$ where $\:\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{C}^{n} \:$ and   $\:z \in \mathbb{C}\:$, could be expressed as
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{y}=\left(z\,\mathrm{I}_{n}\right)\mathbf{x}
\tag{03}
\end{equation}
where $\:\mathrm{I}_{n}\:$ the identity in the linear space, here in $\:\mathbb{C}^{n}$.

Now, the rhs in the 1rst line of (01), that is the term
\begin{equation}
\left(|a\rangle\langle a|\boldsymbol{\xi}\rangle\right)\otimes\left(|b\rangle\langle b|\boldsymbol{\eta}\rangle\right)
\tag{04}
\end{equation}
is essentially a scalar multiple of  $\:\left(|a\rangle\otimes|b\rangle\right)\:$
\begin{equation}
\left(|a\rangle\langle a|\boldsymbol{\xi}\rangle\right)\otimes\left(|b\rangle\langle b|\boldsymbol{\eta}\rangle\right)=\underbrace{\langle a|\boldsymbol{\xi}\rangle  \langle b|\boldsymbol{\eta}\rangle}_{\textrm{scalar quantity}}\left(|a\rangle\otimes|b\rangle\right)     
\tag{05}
\end{equation}
and according to (03) could be expressed as 
\begin{equation}
\left(|a\rangle\langle a|\boldsymbol{\xi}\rangle\right)\otimes\left(|b\rangle\langle b|\boldsymbol{\eta}\rangle\right)=\underbrace{\langle a|\boldsymbol{\xi}\rangle  \langle b|\boldsymbol{\eta}\rangle}_{\textrm{scalar quantity}}\,\mathrm{I}_{12} \left(|a\rangle\otimes|b\rangle\right)     
\tag{06}
\end{equation}
where $\:\mathrm{I}_{12}\:$ the identity in the product space $\:\mathcal{H}_{12}$. But
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{I}_{12}=\mathrm{I}_{1}\otimes\mathrm{I}_{2}  
\tag{07}
\end{equation}
This explains the rhs of the 2nd line of (01).<sup>(1)</sup>

---

**Example**

<sup>Let $\:\mathcal{H}_{1}\equiv \mathbb{R}^{3} \:$,$\:\mathcal{H}_{2}\equiv \mathbb{R}^{2}$. The terms in the identity (02), repeated here for convenience,
\begin{equation}
\bigl(|\mathbf{a}\rangle\langle \mathbf{a}|\bigr)\boldsymbol{\otimes}\bigl(|\mathbf{b}\rangle\langle \mathbf{b}|\bigr)= \bigl(|\mathbf{a}\rangle\boldsymbol{\otimes}|\mathbf{b}\rangle\bigr)\bigl(\langle \mathbf{a}|\boldsymbol{\otimes}\langle \mathbf{b}|\bigr)
\tag{Ex-01}
\end{equation}
will be expressed explicitly by their components and we'll see a verification of this identity.</sup>

<sup>So
\begin{align}
&|\mathbf{a}\rangle=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}\\
a_{2}\\
a_{3}
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}\equiv \mathcal{H}_{1}
\, ,\quad
|\mathbf{b}\rangle=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}\\
b_{2}
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}\equiv \mathcal{H}_{2}
\quad 
\Longrightarrow
\nonumber\\
&|\mathbf{a}\rangle\boldsymbol{\otimes}|\mathbf{b}\rangle=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}\\
a_{2}\\
a_{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{\otimes}
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}\\
b_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}\\
b_{2}
\end{bmatrix}\\
\\
a_{2}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}\\
b_{2}
\end{bmatrix}\\
\\
a_{3}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}\\
b_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}b_{1}\\
a_{1}b_{2}\\
a_{2}b_{1}\\
a_{2}b_{2}\\
a_{3}b_{1}\\
a_{3}b_{2}
\end{bmatrix} \in \underbrace{\mathbb{R}^{3}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\mathbb{R}^{2}=\mathbb{R}^{6}}_{\:\:\:\mathcal{H}_{1}\:\:\boldsymbol{\otimes}\:\:\mathcal{H}_{2}\:\:\:=\:\:\:\mathcal{H}_{12}}
\tag{Ex-02}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
&\langle\mathbf{a}|=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\,,\quad
\langle\mathbf{b}|=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1} & b_{2} 
\end{bmatrix}
\quad 
\Longrightarrow
\langle\mathbf{a}|\boldsymbol{\otimes}\langle\mathbf{b}|=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1} & b_{2} 
\end{bmatrix} &  a_{2}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1} & b_{2} 
\end{bmatrix} & a_{3}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1} & b_{2} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
&\Longrightarrow\langle\mathbf{a}|\boldsymbol{\otimes}\langle\mathbf{b}|=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}b_{1}&a_{1}b_{2}&a_{2}b_{1}&a_{2}b_{2}&a_{3}b_{1}&a_{3}b_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{Ex-03}
\end{align}
Then the transformation in the rhs of (Ex-01) is represented by 
\begin{equation}
\bigl(|\mathbf{a}\rangle\boldsymbol{\otimes}|\mathbf{b}\rangle \bigr)\bigl(  \langle\mathbf{a}|\boldsymbol{\otimes}\langle\mathbf{b}|\bigr) =
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}b_{1}\\
a_{1}b_{2}\\
a_{2}b_{1}\\
a_{2}b_{2}\\
a_{3}b_{1}\\
a_{3}b_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}b_{1}&a_{1}b_{2}&a_{2}b_{1}&a_{2}b_{2}&a_{3}b_{1}&a_{3}b_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{Ex-04}
\end{equation}
that is by the $\:6 \times 6\:$ matrix
\begin{equation}
\bigl(|\mathbf{a}\rangle\boldsymbol{\otimes}|\mathbf{b}\rangle \bigr)\bigl(  \langle\mathbf{a}|\boldsymbol{\otimes}\langle\mathbf{b}|\bigr) =
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}b_{1}a_{1}b_{1} & a_{1}b_{1}a_{1}b_{2} & a_{1}b_{1}a_{2}b_{1} & a_{1}b_{1}a_{2}b_{2} & a_{1}b_{1}a_{3}b_{1}& a_{1}b_{1}a_{3}b_{2}\\
a_{1}b_{2}a_{1}b_{1} & a_{1}b_{2}a_{1}b_{2} & a_{1}b_{2}a_{2}b_{1} & a_{1}b_{2}a_{2}b_{2} & a_{1}b_{2}a_{3}b_{1}& a_{1}b_{2}a_{3}b_{2}\\
a_{2}b_{1}a_{1}b_{1} & a_{2}b_{1}a_{1}b_{2} & a_{2}b_{1}a_{2}b_{1} & a_{2}b_{1}a_{2}b_{2} & a_{2}b_{1}a_{3}b_{1}& a_{2}b_{1}a_{3}b_{2}\\
a_{2}b_{2}a_{1}b_{1} & a_{2}b_{2}a_{1}b_{2} & a_{2}b_{2}a_{2}b_{1} & a_{2}b_{2}a_{2}b_{2} & a_{2}b_{2}a_{3}b_{1}& a_{2}b_{2}a_{3}b_{2}\\
a_{3}b_{1}a_{1}b_{1} & a_{3}b_{1}a_{1}b_{2} & a_{3}b_{1}a_{2}b_{1} & a_{3}b_{1}a_{2}b_{2} & a_{3}b_{1}a_{3}b_{1}& a_{3}b_{1}a_{3}b_{2}\\
a_{3}b_{2}a_{1}b_{1} & a_{3}b_{2}a_{1}b_{2} & a_{3}b_{2}a_{2}b_{1} & a_{3}b_{2}a_{2}b_{2} & a_{3}b_{2}a_{3}b_{1}& a_{3}b_{2}a_{3}b_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{Ex-05}
\end{equation}
Now,
\begin{equation}
|\mathbf{a}\rangle\langle\mathbf{a}|=\mathbf{a}\mathbf{a}^{\boldsymbol{\top}}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}\\
a_{2}\\
a_{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}a_{1} & a_{1}a_{2} & a_{1}a_{3}\\
a_{2}a_{1} & a_{2}a_{2} & a_{2}a_{3}\\
a_{3}a_{1} & a_{3}a_{2} & a_{3}a_{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{Ex-06}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
|\mathbf{b}\rangle\langle\mathbf{b}|=\mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^{\boldsymbol{\top}}=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}\\
b_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1} & b_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}b_{1} & b_{1}b_{2}\\
b_{2}b_{1} & b_{2}b_{2} 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{Ex-07}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{align}
\bigl(|\mathbf{a}\rangle\langle \mathbf{a}|\bigr)\boldsymbol{\otimes}\bigl(|\mathbf{b}\rangle\langle \mathbf{b}|\bigr)&=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}a_{1} & a_{1}a_{2} & a_{1}a_{3}\\
a_{2}a_{1} & a_{2}a_{2} & a_{2}a_{3}\\
a_{3}a_{1} & a_{3}a_{2} & a_{3}a_{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{\otimes}
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}b_{1} & b_{1}b_{2}\\
b_{2}b_{1} & b_{2}b_{2} 
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}a_{1}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}b_{1} & b_{1}b_{2}\\
b_{2}b_{1} & b_{2}b_{2} 
\end{bmatrix} & a_{1}a_{2}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}b_{1} & b_{1}b_{2}\\
b_{2}b_{1} & b_{2}b_{2} 
\end{bmatrix} & a_{1}a_{3}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}b_{1} & b_{1}b_{2}\\
b_{2}b_{1} & b_{2}b_{2} 
\end{bmatrix}\\
a_{2}a_{1}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}b_{1} & b_{1}b_{2}\\
b_{2}b_{1} & b_{2}b_{2} 
\end{bmatrix} & a_{2}a_{2}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}b_{1} & b_{1}b_{2}\\
b_{2}b_{1} & b_{2}b_{2} 
\end{bmatrix} & a_{2}a_{3}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}b_{1} & b_{1}b_{2}\\
b_{2}b_{1} & b_{2}b_{2} 
\end{bmatrix}\\
a_{3}a_{1}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}b_{1} & b_{1}b_{2}\\
b_{2}b_{1} & b_{2}b_{2} 
\end{bmatrix} & a_{3}a_{2}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}b_{1} & b_{1}b_{2}\\
b_{2}b_{1} & b_{2}b_{2} 
\end{bmatrix} & a_{3}a_{3}\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}b_{1} & b_{1}b_{2}\\
b_{2}b_{1} & b_{2}b_{2} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
&
\tag{Ex-08}
\end{align}
that is
\begin{equation}
\bigl(|\mathbf{a}\rangle\langle \mathbf{a}|\bigr)\boldsymbol{\otimes}\bigl(|\mathbf{b}\rangle\langle \mathbf{b}|\bigr) =
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}a_{1}b_{1}b_{1} & a_{1}a_{1}b_{1}b_{2} & a_{1}a_{2}b_{1}b_{1} & a_{1}a_{2}b_{1}b_{2} & a_{1}a_{3}b_{1}b_{1}& a_{1}a_{3}b_{1}b_{2}\\
a_{1}a_{1}b_{2}b_{1} & a_{1}a_{1}b_{2}b_{2} & a_{1}a_{2}b_{2}b_{1} & a_{1}a_{2}b_{2}b_{2} & a_{1}a_{3}b_{2}b_{1}& a_{1}a_{3}b_{2}b_{2}\\
a_{2}a_{1}b_{1}b_{1} & a_{2}a_{1}b_{1}b_{2} & a_{2}a_{2}b_{1}b_{1} & a_{2}a_{2}b_{1}b_{2} & a_{2}a_{3}b_{1}b_{1}& a_{2}a_{3}b_{1}b_{2}\\
a_{2}a_{1}b_{2}b_{1} & a_{2}a_{1}b_{2}b_{2} & a_{2}a_{2}b_{2}b_{1} & a_{2}a_{2}b_{2}b_{2} & a_{2}a_{3}b_{2}b_{1}& a_{2}a_{3}b_{2}b_{2}\\
a_{3}a_{1}b_{1}b_{1} & a_{3}a_{1}b_{1}b_{2} & a_{3}a_{2}b_{1}b_{1} & a_{3}a_{2}b_{1}b_{2} & a_{3}a_{3}b_{1}b_{1}& a_{3}a_{3}b_{1}b_{2}\\
a_{3}a_{1}b_{2}b_{1} & a_{3}a_{1}b_{2}b_{2} & a_{3}a_{2}b_{2}b_{1} & a_{3}a_{2}b_{2}b_{2} & a_{3}a_{3}b_{2}b_{1}& a_{3}a_{3}b_{2}b_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{Ex-09}
\end{equation}
The matrices in the right hand sides of equations (Ex-05) and (Ex-09) are equal, so the left hand sides, verifying the validity of the identity (Ex-01).</sup>

---

<sup>(1)
I suggest to take a look in my 2nd and 3rd answers therein : [Total spin of two spin-1/2 particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342123/total-spin-of-two-spin-1-2-particles/342156#342156) about product states, product spaces and product transformations which, although used for spin, give informations and details in general.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Great and detailed answer!! You really helped me a lot.