# Generator of 3D rotations in $\mathbb{C}^2 \otimes \mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, representation-theory, lie-algebra

Let us consider a system of two spinors. The 3D rotation operator around the $\vec{n}$ axis in $\mathbb{C}^2$ is clearly $R(\theta) = \exp(i \frac{\theta}{2}\vec{n}\cdot\vec{\sigma})$.

If I wish to rotate my system of two spinors around the $z$ axis for instance, which one is the generator of rotations, $S^1_z \otimes S^2_z$ or $S^1_z \otimes \mathbb{I}+ \mathbb{I} \otimes S^2_z$?

Comment: The second suggestion.

Comment: Then can you rotate them through different axes? For example if we took  $S^1_{x_1} \otimes \mathbb{I}+ \mathbb{I} \otimes S^2_{x_2}$ for axes $x_1$ and $x_2$? Would it make any sense? It's not really a possible rotation for the system, is it?

Comment: Related : [Total spin of two spin- 1/2  particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342123/total-spin-of-two-spin-1-2-particles/342156#342156)  **1. T H I R D__ A N S W E R**  equation (62)
**2. FOURTH__A N S W E R**  equations (68), (69), (70).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the second one. To derive this, consider a finite rotation $|\psi_i \rangle \to |\psi' \rangle = U_{ij}(\theta) |\psi_j\rangle$. Acting on a tensor product, we have
$$|\psi_i \rangle |\phi_k \rangle \to U_{ij}(\theta) U_{kl}(\theta) |\psi_j\rangle  |\phi_l\rangle.$$
If $\theta$ is an infinitesimal angle, we can write
$$
U_{ij}(\theta) = \delta_{ij} + \theta S_{ij} + O(\theta^2)$$
where $S$ is a Lie algebra generator. Hence
$$|\psi_i \rangle |\phi_k \rangle \to |\psi_i \rangle |\phi_k \rangle  + \theta \left[ (S_{ij} |\psi_j \rangle) \otimes |\phi_k \rangle +  |\psi_i \rangle \otimes (S_{kl}|\phi_l \rangle) \right] + O(\theta^2).$$
The term inside brackets is precisely of the form $S^1 \otimes \mathbb{1} + \mathbb{1} \otimes S^2$.