# Product states - Addition of angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

In the book [Quantum Mechanics](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-03170-4_10) - Franz Schwabl, in chapter 10, equation (10.4) says

Since all the properties of angular momenta and their eigenstates hold for the total angular momentum J .We can construct the product states:
$$|j_1m_1j_2m_2\rangle=|j_1m_1\rangle|j_2m_2\rangle$$

I want to know why multiplication? instead of other relations like:
$$|j_1m_1j_2m_2\rangle=|j_1m_1\rangle+|j_2m_2\rangle$$

or

$$|j_1m_1j_2m_2\rangle=|j_1m_1\rangle^2|j_2m_2\rangle^2$$

or some weird relations?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Related : [Total spin of two spin-1/2 particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342123/total-spin-of-two-spin-1-2-particles/342156#342156)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The true way of seeing this is that the states are written as a *tensor product* in that the total Hilbert space is formed of ordered products of states of the form
$$\left|j_{1}m_{1}\right> \otimes \left|j_{2}m_{2}\right>.$$
Moreover the so-called addition of angular momentum should really be written as 
$$J_{T} = J_{1}\otimes \mathbb{I} + \mathbb{I} \otimes J_{2}$$
so that $J_{1}$ acts only on the first element of the tensor product, $\left|j_{1}m_{1}\right>$ and $J_{2}$ on the second element, $\left|j_{2}m_{2}\right>$.

To see this geometrically we note that having fixed an arbitrary direction as $\hat{z}$ the angular momentum in that direction is additive.