# Isospin and Clebsch Gordan coefficients

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, isospin-symmetry

If I have to combine 2 spin $\frac{1}{2}$ particles I do with Clebsch Gordan coefficients so that for example $|{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}\rangle|{\frac{1}{2},\frac{-1}{2}}\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|{1,0}\rangle+|{0,0}\rangle)$. Now if I have to calculate C-G coefficients for this new state and another state for example $|{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}\rangle$, how I have to do?

Comment: Surely you can find any of a quasi-infinite number of texts where this elementary done in great details.

Comment: Related (if not duplicate) : [Τotal spin of two spin-1/2 particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342123/total-spin-of-two-spin-1-2-particles/342156#342156).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to you "Lie Algebra in particle physics" by Howard Georgi, section 3.5, he gives a very detailed example.

The idea is to start with the highest spin state: in your example it's $\big|1,1\big\rangle = \big|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\big\rangle\big|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\big\rangle$ and then act with the lowering operator $J^-$.

for instance for the first time you get
\begin{align}
 J^-\big|1,1\big\rangle &= J^-\left(\big|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\big\rangle\big|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\big\rangle\right)\\
\big|1,0\big\rangle&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\big|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\big\rangle\big|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\big\rangle+|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\big\rangle\big|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\big\rangle\right)
\end{align}