# An essential exercise involving spin composition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, spinors

> Suppose we have two particles with spin $1/2$. They have $S^{tot}=1$ and $S^{tot}_y=0$.
> How can we write the state of the system in terms of the eigenstates of $S_{1z},S_{2z}$?

My attempt:
I would like to divide the problem in two: firstly we write the state of the system in terms of the states of $S_{1y},S_{2y}$ and then we re-write the state in terms of $S_{1z},S_{2z}$:
We know that it's always true that:
$$S^{tot}_y=S_{1y}+S_{2y}$$
this is a fundamental rule of the spin's algebra, right? So:
$$0=S_{1y}+S_{2y}$$
but of course this last two can only be $+1/2$ or $-1/2$, so the possible states are:
$$|+1/2,-1/2\rangle  \ \ \ or \ \ \ |-1/2,+1/2\rangle$$
I then state that the more general solution is the linear combination of this two possibilities, and so (let me call $+1/2$ simply $+$ and $-1/2$ simply $-$):
$$|S^{tot}=1,S^{tot}_y=0\rangle =a|+,-\rangle+b|-,+\rangle$$
For me this should be the solution. **But:** in my lecture notes it's stated that the **true solution** is:
$$|S^{tot}=1,S^{tot}_y=0\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[|+,-\rangle+|-,+\rangle\right] \tag{1}$$
I don't get why this must be true, remember that the particles are not identical. This is my *first problem.*

But suppose that we do not have this problem, let's assume (1) to be correct. Then how can I translate (1) from $y$ to $z$? **What is the link? How does the link work?** This is my *second problem.*

I would like to understand what I am getting right and what I am getting wrong.

Comment: When you say $S_y^{tot}=S_{1y}+S_{2y}$ and $0=S_{1y}+S_{2y}$, do the $S$s refer to operators or eigenvalues?

Comment: 1. Have you evaluated $S^\text{tot}$ on your "general solution"? Your reasoning to arrive at it used only $S^\text{tot}_y = 0$, but you have an additional datum of $S^\text{tot} = 1$ that you haven't used. 2. I do not understand what "translation from $y$ to $z$" is supposed to mean or what "link" you mean in that part of your question. Could you be more explicit about what you want to do here?

Comment: @ACuriousMind 1. You are right, but how can I use the datum of $s^{tot}=1$ in this situation? 2.Look at the problem at the start of my answer: we need to express the state that is now in the base of the total angular momentum in $y$ in the base of the angular momentum of the two particles along $z$. Once we get equation (1) how can we move forward to answer the question in the problem? I would really appreciate an answer instead of a comment, I think my inability of solving this problem reflects something I do not understand, and so a complete answer from you would be great!

Comment: Related : [Total spin of two spin- 1/2  particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342123/total-spin-of-two-spin-1-2-particles/342156#342156).

Answer (score 1):

Let us first fix clearer notation. We call the spin *operators* on the $i$-th particle $S_{ix}$ (and so on) and their eigenvalues $s_{ix}$ (and so on). $S_i^2 = S_{ix}^2 + S_{iy}^2 + S_{iz}^2$ is the Casimir operator of the rotation algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ has a single eigenvalue $s_i(s_i + 1)$ on irreducible representations of the rotation algebra. For the "total" operators and eigenvalues on the combined two-particle space we just drop the $i$ subscript. In this notation your question asks you to find the two-particle state with $s = 1$ and $s_y = 0$ in terms of eigenstates of $S_{z}$.

1. You have correctly determined that a general eigenstate of $S_y$ has the form $a\lvert +,-\rangle + b\lvert -,+\rangle$ in terms of eigenstates of the $S_{iy}$. But you also need it to be an eigenstate of $S^2$ with the eigenvalue $1(1+1) = 2$.
2. Since the eigenstates of each of the $S_{ix},S_{iy},S_{iz}$ form a basis for the one-particle space, the eigenstates of one of these operators can be expressed as a linear combination of the eigenstates of another of these operators. The notation $\lvert +,-\rangle$ is just shorthand for $\lvert +\rangle \otimes \lvert -\rangle$, so by linearity of the tensor product the expressions from the one-particle space straightforwardly extend to the two-particle space - just plug them in and multiply out.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I have asked this question exactly because I am not well versed in angular momentum algebra yet. How exactly can we use the fact that $S^{tot}=1$ to derive the correct form? Can you show all the steps? And also: How can I do the second calculation? Do I have to use Pauli Matrices? How?

Comment: @Noumeno We do not give complete answers to homework-like questions here, so I will not show all the steps. I do not understand what about "you need your state to be an eigenstate of $S^2$ with eigenvalue 2" is not specific enough for you to figure out what to do.

Comment: Ok, I respect your position. The problem is that I didn't have the chance to study su(2) algebra yet. All this spin algebra was poorly introduced to me, and for this reason I would appreciate a complete solution. But I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

*(Brief introduction about spin for a $1/2$ particle)*

If for a particle with spin $s=1/2$ the set of commuting operators $\left\{S_y,\boldsymbol{S}^2\right\}$ is chosen as basis, then one may label the states according to the $\pm 1/2$ eigenstates of $S_y$ (I will use the following notation instead of your simplified one because it will be useful when addressing your second point of the question)

$$S_y|S_y;\pm\rangle=\pm\frac{1}{2}|S_y;\pm\rangle\tag{1}\label{sy}$$

with total angular momentum

$$\boldsymbol{S}^2|S_y;\pm\rangle=\frac{3}{4}|S_y;\pm\rangle\tag{2}\label{s2}$$

One may introduce raising and lowering operators as $S_\pm=S_x\pm \mathrm{i}S_z$ whose actions yield

$$S_+|S_y;+\rangle=0,\quad S_+|S_y;-\rangle=|S_y;+\rangle\tag{3}\label{s+}$$

along with

$$S_-|S_y;-\rangle=0,\quad S_-|S_y;+\rangle=|S_y;-\rangle\tag{4}\label{s-}$$

*(Moving to a system of two particles of spin $1/2$)*

The total spin along $Oy$, whose eigenvalue you seek to be null, that it $s_y^\mathrm{tot}=0$ (notice I denoted the eigenvalue with small letter in order to not cause any confusion) would be given by

$$S_y^\mathrm{tot}=S_y^1\otimes\mathsf{I}_2+\mathsf{I}_1\otimes S_y^2\tag{5}\label{sytot}$$

This may seem just spin with extra steps but I always find it useful when I know on which space the operators act (the identity was denoted by $\mathsf{I}$).

There aren't many possibilities. Direct computations show that states of the type $|S_y;+\rangle|S_y;+\rangle$ would yield $s_y^{tot}=1$, states $|S_y;-\rangle|S_y;-\rangle$ give $s_y^{tot}=-1$. Nevertheless, the states $|S_y;+\rangle|S_y;-\rangle$ and $|S_y;-\rangle|S_y;+\rangle$ result in, via direct computation using \eqref{sytot}, the eigenvalue $s_y^{tot}=0$. Therefore, a state with $s_y^{tot}=0$ must be a linear combination of the type

$$|s_y^{tot}=0\rangle=a|S_y;+\rangle|S_y;-\rangle+b|S_y;-\rangle|S_y;+\rangle\tag{6}\label{state}$$

where the coefficients must of course satisfy $a^2+b^2=1$ as a normalization condition. This is a result which you also obtained but I just wanted to go through it with my notation.

On the other hand, the total spin of a composite system may be expanded as

$$\boldsymbol{S}^2=(\boldsymbol{S}^1)^2\otimes\mathsf{I}_2+\mathsf{I}_1\otimes(\boldsymbol{S}^2)^2+2\boldsymbol{S}^1\otimes\boldsymbol{S}^2\tag{7}\label{s2tot}$$

It is useful to express the term $\boldsymbol{S}^1\boldsymbol{S}^2$ (I'm dropping the direct product term since too much rigurosity is slowing my typesetting) as

$$\boldsymbol{S}^1\boldsymbol{S}^2=\underbrace{S_x^1S_x^2+S_z^1S_z^2}_{\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{2}(S_+^1S_-^2+S_-^1S_+^2)}+S_y^1S_y^2\tag{8}\label{s1s2}$$

Now one may proceed to act with the total spin from \eqref{s2tot}, along with the term from \eqref{s1s2}, on the proposed state \eqref{state}. The computation is not difficult, it just uses repeatedly the action of the operators from \eqref{sy}, \eqref{s2}, \eqref{s+} and \eqref{s-}. There might be a shorter more elegant way to derive it than with raising and lowering operators. Nevertheless, the final result reads

$$\boldsymbol{S}^2|s_y^{tot}=0\rangle=(a+b)|S_y;+\rangle|S_y;-\rangle+(a+b)|S_y;-\rangle|S_y;+\rangle $$

One is interested in states having $s^\mathrm{tot}=1$ which imply

$$\boldsymbol{S}^2|s_y^{tot}=0\rangle=\underbrace{s^\mathrm{tot}(s^\mathrm{tot}+1)}_{\displaystyle 2}|s_y^{tot}=0\rangle\stackrel{\eqref{state}}=2a|S_y;+\rangle|S_y;-\rangle+2b|S_y;-\rangle|S_y;+\rangle$$

Therefore $a=b$ and along with $a^2+b^2=1$ and assuming $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, the state characterized by $s_y^{tot}=0$ and $s^{tot}=1$ is

$$|s_y^{tot}=0, s^{tot}=1\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|S_y;+\rangle|S_y;-\rangle+|S_y;-\rangle|S_y;+\rangle)\tag{9}\label{finalstate}$$

Now that we have the state, the following question was how to express it in the basis (for each particle) labeled by the eigenvalues of $\left\{S_z,\boldsymbol{S}^2\right\}$ (at least this is how I understood it, correct me if I am mistaken).

This would somehow assume that you now do a measurement of spin along another axis, which should erase the information measured before. It is then fair to assume that it is equally probable to obtain projections of spin along $Oz$ of $\pm 1/2$, irrespective of what you obtained before along $Oy$, thus

$$|\langle S_y;+|S_z,+\rangle|^2=|\langle S_y;-|S_z,+\rangle|^2=\frac{1}{2}$$

Consequently, one may expand

$$|S_z,+\rangle=\underbrace{\langle S_y;+|S_z;+\rangle}_{\displaystyle\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}|S_y;+\rangle+\underbrace{\langle S_y;-|S_z;+\rangle}_{\displaystyle\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}|S_y;-\rangle$$

and similarly (but with a change in sign which will be explained immediately)

$$|S_z,-\rangle=\underbrace{\langle S_y;+|S_z;-\rangle}_{\displaystyle\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}|S_y;+\rangle+\underbrace{\langle S_y;-|S_z;-\rangle}_{\displaystyle-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}|S_y;-\rangle$$

where the change in sign is chosen in order to assure

$$|\langle S_z;+|S_z,-\rangle|=0$$

Therfore, you have your $\left\{|S_y;\pm\rangle\right\}$ basis expressed in terms of $\left\{|S_z;\pm\rangle\right\}$ as

$$|S_y;+\rangle=\frac{1}{2}(|S_z;+\rangle)+|S_z;-\rangle),\quad|S_y;-\rangle=\frac{1}{2}(|S_z;+\rangle)-|S_z;-\rangle)$$

which allow you to immediately express your state from \eqref{finalstate} in this basis now labeled by the eigenstates of $S_z^1,S_z^2$.