# Why scale tensor products like that?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, angular-momentum, tensor-calculus

Studying the sum of angular momentum in quantum mechanics, tensor products were introduced to us to get the general system from the individual states. There's a property that says: $(av)\otimes w = a(v \otimes w)= v\otimes (aw)  $. We will call it (1).
But I don't get it's physical meaning. It's as if I scale one vector, but not the other, and the vector of the total system scales by that factor¿?.

For example, for two particles with spin $\frac{1}{2}$, I have the state $ |\frac{1}{2},m_1\rangle \otimes |\frac{1}{2},m_2\rangle $ for $m_i=\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}$. If I measure the $z$ component of the spin of the first particle ($S_1$), I get the value $\hbar m_1$, with $|\frac{1}{2},m1\rangle$ an eigenvector of that operator. Hence, we have that: $ (S_{1,z} \otimes 1) (|\frac{1}{2},m_1\rangle \otimes |\frac{1}{2},m_2\rangle)=(\hbar m_1 |\frac{1}{2},m_1\rangle) \otimes |\frac{1}{2},m_2\rangle  $ and by the property (1) that's just equal to:   $ \hbar m_1( |\frac{1}{2},m_1\rangle \otimes |\frac{1}{2},m_2\rangle)$. Which seems to imply that $|\frac{1}{2},m_1\rangle \otimes |\frac{1}{2},m_2\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $S_{1,z} \otimes 1$ with eigenvalue $\hbar m_1$ (the measurement of state 1 is scaling the total system by that factor). Or what's worse, by the third equality in (1), that: $ (S_{1,z} \otimes 1) (|\frac{1}{2},m_1\rangle \otimes |\frac{1}{2},m_2\rangle)= |\frac{1}{2},m_1\rangle \otimes (\hbar m_1 |\frac{1}{2},m_2\rangle) $  (that the measurement in the first state scales the second one by that factor ¿¿¿???).
But that's not the case in reality. The measurement in state 1 doesn't change things that way.

I don't get what's going on, I don't understand much tensor products. If you can shed some light on this.

Comment: This would be so much easier to read if you formatted the $m_{1,2}$ with subscripts, $\frac{1}{2}$ as proper fractions and the angle brackets using $\langle,\rangle$ (\langle, \rangle).

Comment: *"But that's not the case in reality."* - if I've read what you've written correctly, all the things you've said are true. Why do you think they are "not the case in reality"?

Comment: Thanks for the advice @jacob1729, I have changed it

Comment: @ACuriousMind because by measuring the first state, I'm altering the second one scaling it? I don't get it. Isn't it supposed that they are independent? I just don't see how this property manifest in reality, or in the measurement process

Comment: Related : [Total spin of two spin-1/2 particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342123/total-spin-of-two-spin-1-2-particles/342156#342156).

Answer (score 1):

This is because of geometry.

Tensors actually generalise vectors to higher dimensional arrows. Whilst a  vector is a single arrow, a 2-tensor, which was can also call a 2-vector, is defined by two arrows and so on.

This means, that  whilst there is only one way of adding two vectors - the usual parallelogram law - there are 2 ways of adding 2-tensors and 5 ways of adding 5-tensors and so on. And these additions are just generalisations of the vector additivity law. It's quite clear if you draw out the second and third cases - the higher cases obviously can't be drawn in our 3d world.

This takes care of the additivity of tensors. Your question is about the internal scaling of tensors where $au \otimes v = u \otimes av = a(u \otimes v)$.

Again this is a geometric property, it means that we can recale a tensor whilst keeping its geometric area the same. If you draw a 2-tensor, that is a 2-vector as two arrows so that they form a parallelogram, you'll see that rescaling one side by $a$ means that you must rescale the other side by $1/a$, and hence the geometric area remains the same. I recommend drawing out the diagram as it's quite clear then.

Tensors are very geometric notions, although typically they aren't introduced in this fashion.