# Determination of isospin probabilities

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, probability, isospin-symmetry

I have the following problem:  If
$| I I_3 \rangle  = \alpha |1/2,-1/2 \rangle |1,1\rangle + \beta |1/2,1/2 \rangle |1,0\rangle $, are the isospin and the third component of the isospin, calculate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ when $I=3/2$ and $I_3 = 1/2$.

The solution is $\alpha = \sqrt{1/3}$ and $\beta = \sqrt{2/3}$, but I don't know how to arrive to it because I don't understand the notation ($|a,b\rangle|c,d\rangle$).
Can you please explain me this notation and the method to solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: If you want to understand in deep detail how to combine two angular momenta or two isospins see my answers therein : [Total spin of two spin- 1/2  particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342123/total-spin-of-two-spin-1-2-particles/342156#342156). Especially the **Example** in my **FIFTH__ANSWER** is what you are looking for and more exactly equation (Ex-26.4).

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the problem of composition of angular momentum states since the isospin algebra is identical to the algebra of angular momentum.  The notation $\vert a,b\rangle\vert c,d\rangle$ thus refers to:

1. $\vert a,b\rangle$ for particle 1, with isospin $a$ and isospin projection $b$,
2. $\vert c,d\rangle$ for particle 2, with isospin $c$ and isospin projection $d$,
3. $\vert II_3\rangle$ for the combined system, with isospin $I$ and isospin projection $I_3$.

Thus the coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of your linear combinations are the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients $C^{II_3}_{ab;cd}$.  They can be looked up in tables or obtained using various programs (*v.g.* Mathematica).