# Definition of tensor product in Nielsen & Chuang "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator

Nielsen and Chuang (Quantum Computation and Quantum Information, 2010) define the tensor product of linear operators acting on vector spaces on page 73. Therefore the tensor product used in the definition of the reduced density matrix on page 105 via $|a_1\rangle \langle a_2|\otimes|b_1\rangle \langle b_2|$ is defined, because both outer products are linear operators according to earlier statements. Although it seems to me that the tensor product used on page 102 via $\rho_1\otimes\rho_2 \otimes\dots\otimes\rho_n$ isn't defined, because in the book I can't find any hint that might link the density operator to linear operators. I'm sure the tensor product that is used on page 102 is defined properly, so what is it that I don't get?

Comment: Density operator is a linear operator.

Comment: Are all operators used in "entry level" quantum mechanics (density operator, unitary operars for rotations in the bloch sphere, hermitian operaors for measurements) linear?

Comment: @manuel459 The answer is an unequivocal yes.

Comment: The only exception is anti-unitary operators, which are anti-linear.

Comment: Not Strictly Related :[Total spin of two spin- 1/2  particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342123/total-spin-of-two-spin-1-2-particles/342156#342156), **SECOND & THIRD_ANSWER**.