# Products of wavefunction spin parts

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

Spin up is described by a vector $\uparrow=(1\;0)^T$ and spin down by $\downarrow=(0\;1)^T$. When we write e.g. $\uparrow \uparrow$ what kind of product does it mean?

Comment: Two spin up particles?

Comment: It is a [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product). See the "From bases" construction near the top of the page. The rest you don't need. Really, your quantum book should give you enough to figure out how to manipulate these objects and what they mean.

Comment: Related : [Total spin of two spin- 1/2  particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342123/total-spin-of-two-spin-1-2-particles/342156#342156).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle #1 \rvert}$
$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert #1 \rangle}$
$\newcommand{\avec}[2]{\left(\begin{matrix}#1 \\ #2 \end{matrix}\right)}$
$\newcommand{\bvec}[4]{\left(\begin{matrix}#1 \\ #2 \\ #3 \\ #4 \end{matrix}\right)}$

> Spin up is described by a vector $\uparrow=(1\;0)^T$ and spin down by $\downarrow=(0\;1)^T$. When we write e.g. $\uparrow \uparrow$ what kind of product does it mean?

As stated in the comments, this is a tensor product.

Just like the original vectors can be represented by matrices (2-by-1 matrices), so too the tensor product vectors can be represented by matrices (4-by-1 matrices).

For example:
$$
\uparrow\uparrow = \avec{1}{0}\times\avec{1}{0} = \avec{1\avec{1}{0}}{0\avec{1}{0}} = \bvec{1}{0}{0}{0}
$$

For example:
$$
\uparrow\downarrow = \avec{1}{0}\times\avec{0}{1} = \avec{1\avec{0}{1}}{0\avec{0}{1}} = \bvec{0}{1}{0}{0}
$$

And so on.