# Tensor product question in quantum computing context

Tags: quantum-computer

I understand the basics of how to evaluate tensor products. For example:
$$\sigma_z \otimes I = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\sigma_z$ is the pauli z matrix and $I$ is the 2x2 identity.

My question arises when applying this math to two qubits. There are four operations to consider:
$$1)\hspace{1cm}\sigma_z^{(1)} \otimes I^{(2)}$$
$$2)\hspace{1cm}I^{(2)} \otimes\sigma_z^{(1)}$$
$$3)\hspace{1cm}\sigma_z^{(2)} \otimes I^{(1)}$$
$$4)\hspace{1cm}I^{(1)} \otimes \sigma_z^{(2)}$$

Where the superscript denotes the qubit that the operation (gate) is applied to. So are $1)$ and $2)$ the same $4\times 4$ matrix? Or are $1)$ and $3)$ the same matrix. I guess my question can be summarized is it the order or the superscript/qubit that matters when evaluating out these tensor products into matrix form?

Comment: Can you write the four matrices? It will be clearer to point out where you are getting it wrong that way.

Comment: It is to my understanding that if you add the qubit labels, the tensor product in your notation is commutative.

Comment: Based on @Mauricio's comment, where it is true that the tensor product is *abstractly* commutative if you label the operators with a qubit label, then 1 and 2 are the same operator, and 3 and 4 are the same operator.  When you write operators in a basis and make a matrix representation, then the order *absolutely matters*, and you have to choose one of $\sigma_z^{(1)}\otimes I^{(2)}$ or $I^{(2)}\otimes \sigma_z^{(1)}$ to perform the  *matrix* tensor product.

Comment: Related : [Total spin of two spin- 1/2  particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342123/total-spin-of-two-spin-1-2-particles/342156#342156).